# cursor not working although i have records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have following cursor in sql:

```
DECLARE cur_saveRate CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT UtilityName,SuggestedRate,Client,State,CurrentRate,AccNo,Savings from #tempXML


print '1'

OPEN cur_saveRate 



IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
BEGIN 

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_saveRate INTO @UTILITY_NAME,@SUG_RATE,@CLIENT_NAME,@CLIENT_STATE,@CURRENT_RATE,@ACCOUNT_NUMBER,@SAVINGS

 WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
 BEGIN

..........
.........

END
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_saveRate INTO @UTILITY_NAME,@SUG_RATE,@CLIENT_NAME,@CLIENT_STATE,@CURRENT_RATE,@ACCOUNT_NUMBER,@SAVINGS

END

CLOSE cur_saveRate
DEALLOCATE cur_saveRate
```

Unfortunately it does not comes into cursor.

I tried to print 'something'  on various places it does not comes into cursor.

I have made sure that records are present into `#tempXML`

Please help me.

Comment: I just noticed that the variable that you use in your Fetch next is different from the variable that you use in the declaration.  Your code may execute inside the IF condition but not inside the WHILE statement.

Comment: Try changing cur_emp with cur_saveRate

Comment: @SetrákusRa yeah that was mistake , but i changed it now.. now also cursor not running

Comment: Try to **get rid** of the cursor altogether and replace this with a nice, **set-based** approach .....

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably because of the condition `IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0`

As per BOL `@@CURSOR_ROWS less than 0` indicates

> The number returned by @@CURSOR_ROWS is negative if the last cursor was opened asynchronously. Keyset-driver or static cursors are opened asynchronously if the value for sp_configure cursor threshold is greater than 0 and the number of rows in the cursor result set is greater than the cursor threshold.

MSDN Reference on this is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx).

Try getting rid of this condition and run the cursor.

Comment: I removed that, but still it was not executing

Comment: OK if removing this condition did not work, lets troubleshoot. Please put the statement `SELECT 'Something'` just after the first `FETCH NEXT..` Does it print "Something"?

Comment: no..it was total failure.. i done it with plain while loop.. thanks for your co operation